# How to import non-version controlled branches to git?

Tags: git, migration, cvs, git-merge

We used to use CVS in our team and we are trying to migrate to git, but for some strange reason one of the programmers has been working on a big project by manually updating the branches instead of using version control. This has led to many human error discrepancies in the code and we're not sure where to go from here.

Right now we are waiting on that programmer to consolidate those branches before importing to git, but it is taking way too long.
We are considering importing all the branches separately and then merging them in git. We're just not sure how to do this with non-version controlled branches.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: One way to do this would be to create a new branch from your versioned repo, and then paste over the source with the source from the non-versioned branch.  You would then clean everything up, commit, and you would have a versioned branch.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What if there's been a lot of changes made to a lot of files. Is there any way to do this automatically? Would git merge be able to handle something like this?

Comment: You need some way to get into the Git "system," and my first comment might be one way to do this.  Once you have an actual Git feature branch which shares an ancestor with `master`, then the problem reduces to a simple `git merge`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Could you add your comment as an answer?

Comment: Adding now...give me 2 miniutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you can try to solve your problem.  Assuming you are beginning on your `master` branch, first create a new feature branch which will hold the programmer's manual version of the project:

```
git checkout -b feature
```

Next, you can copy the root directory containing the programmer's project and paste it on top of the root of the `feature` branch you just created.  I see three possibilities happening with each file:

- a new file which only the programmer had will be added
- a shared file will be overwritten by the programmer's version
- a shared file will added in a location different than its location in the `feature` branch

Take a deep breath, and type `git status` from the Git console.  You will likely see evidence of all three scenarios, possibly also including directories.  Pay attention to what you see, because you will be dealing with these files in the final step.

Next add every file to the Git index and commit via

```
git add path/to/file
git commit -m 'programmer branch created'
```

Don't be afraid to use wildcards if that speeds things up for you, e.g. `git add dir/*`

Now you have a bona-fide Git feature branch representing the work which the programmer did.  For the final step, you can try merging thigs branch into `master` via:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

There will be lots of conflicts, but if you apply some insight you should be able to determine a plan for resolving them.